# how could you copy any src image from one side to another side droppable with method bind and url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

you can copy only one image to the droppable area with the bind method and url with javascript but you can not change any image,

i tried sourceImage = new Image() but the plugin only works with url

```
<div class="draggable">
   <img src='team.jpg' class="resizable ui-resizable draggable" style="width:300px"/>
</div>
<div class="draggable">
   <img src='foto11.jpg' class="resizable ui-resizable draggable" style="width:300px"/>
</div>
<div id="vanilla-demo" class='droppable' style="width:356px;height:286px;position:absolute;top:29.1em;left:73px;background-color: yellow">   
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(".draggable").draggable({cursor:"grabbing",helper:"clone",opacity:0.8,grid:[20,20]});
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        op: function(event,ui) {
            vanilla.bind({
                url: 'team.jpg',
                orientation: 4
                });
            }
    });
    var el = document.getElementById('vanilla-demo');
    var vanilla = new Croppie(el, {
        viewport: { width: 300, height: 250 },
        boundary: { width: 300, height: 250 },
        showZoomer: true,
        enableOrientation: false
    });
    vanilla.bind({
        url: '',
        orientation: 4
    });
</script>
```

I hope the url shows the image when drope the image,

Comment: What specifically is not working? Also do you mean `drop:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drag an item to a droppable, you can use the `ui.draggable` passed into drop.

> **drop( event, ui )**
>
> Triggered when an accepted draggable is dropped on the droppable (based on the `tolerance` option).
>
> - event
> - ui
>
>   - draggable *Type: jQuery* A jQuery object representing the draggable element.

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var el = $('#vanilla-demo');

  var vanilla = new Croppie(el[0], {
    viewport: {
      width: 300,
      height: 250
    },
    boundary: {
      width: 300,
      height: 250
    },
    showZoomer: true,
    enableOrientation: false
  });

  vanilla.bind({
    url: '',
    orientation: 4
  });

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    cursor: "grabbing",
    helper: "clone",
    opacity: 0.8,
    grid: [20, 20],
    zIndex: 1002
  });

  $(".droppable").droppable({
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var newImage = ui.draggable;
      vanilla.bind({
        url: newImage.attr("src"),
        orientation: 4
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.droppable {
  width: 356px;
  height: 286px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 29.1em;
  left: 73px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.4/croppie.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.4/croppie.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="draggable">
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/WDds7On.jpg' class="resizable ui-resizable draggable" style="width:300px" />
</div>
<div class="draggable">
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/p77MNQh.jpg' class="resizable ui-resizable draggable" style="width:300px" />
</div>
<div id="vanilla-demo" class='droppable'></div>
```

When the new item is dropped, the Binding is updated for Croppie.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @FrankPaniagua thats great! If it answers your question, I hope you will upvote and mark it as the answer.